# Return an Arrray of Objects with key/value pairs using webmethod/pagemethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

I would like get an Array of objects and get a value based on the key.

Something like this javascript:

```
PageMethods.GetProducts(function(results) {
   var productName  = results[0].name;
});
```

I've tried this in code behind, but I get an array of arrays in the results:

VB

```
<WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function GetProducts() As ArrayList

        Dim products As New ArrayList

        Dim prAdptr As New DataSet1TableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter
        Dim prTbl As DataSet1.ProductsDataTable = prAdptr.GetData
        Dim prRow As DataSet1.ProductsRow

        For Each prRow In prTbl
            Dim product As New Collection
            product.Add(prRow.ProductID, "id")
            product.Add(prRow.ProductName, "name")

            products.Add(product)
        Next

        Return products
    End Function
```

c#

```
[WebMethod()]
public static ArrayList GetProducts()
{

    ArrayList products = new ArrayList();

    DataSet1TableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter prAdptr = new DataSet1TableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter();
    DataSet1.ProductsDataTable prTbl = prAdptr.GetData;
    DataSet1.ProductsRow prRow = default(DataSet1.ProductsRow);

    foreach ( prRow in prTbl) {
        Collection product = new Collection();
        product.Add(prRow.ProductID, "id");
        product.Add(prRow.ProductName, "name");

        products.Add(product);
    }

    return products;
}
```

Therefore I can't get value based on a key.
I know i can reference the position of the value like so:

```
results[0][0];
```

but this is not ideal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Anonymous Types` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

```
foreach ( prRow in prTbl) {
    products.Add(new {
        id=prRow.ProductID,
        name=prRow.ProductName
    });
}
```